# C++ Debugging console app

Tags: c++

I'm working on a debugging console app for school, and I get an error when compiling the program.

```
//DEBUG9-4
//This program creates Student objects
//and overloads < to compare student year in school
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
   private: //MISSING :
     int stuID;
     int year;
     double gpa;
   public:
     Student(const int i, const int y, const double g); // NO VARIABLES DECLARED HERE
     void showYear(); //MISSING THE CURLY BRACES
    bool operator < (const Student);
};
Student::Student(const int i, const int y, const double g) // VARIABLES WERE NOT MATCHING
{
  stuID = i;
  year = i;
  gpa = g; // VARIABLE g WAS POST TO BE THE "gpa" VARIABLE
}
void Student::showYear()
{
  cout << year;
}
int Student::operator < (const Student otherStu)
{
   bool less = false;
   if (year < otherStu.year)
      less = true;
   return less;
}
int main()
{
   Student a(111, 2, 3.50), b(222, 1, 3.00);
   if(a < b)
   {
      a.showYear();
      cout << " is less than ";
      b.showYear();
   }
   else
   {
      a.showYear();
      cout << " is not less than ";
      b.showYear();
   }
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Line: 28 Error: prototype for 'int Student::operator < (const Student& otherStu)' dose not match any in class Students.
Line: 16 Error: candidate is: bool Student::operator<(Student).

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me - you've declared the function one way, but implemented it a different way. Declaration and definition should match.

Comment: What you have is a compilation (or build) error. It's not about debugging (which is done at run-time).

Comment: Take another look at `Student::Student(const int i, const int y, const double g)`. You may have a compiler warning here. Do not ignore compiler warnings.  Compiler errors prevent the compiler from creating a program, but compiler warnings are telling you that the program probably won't work the way you want  it to. Compiler warnings are your first line of defense against simple mistakes, so turn them up LOUD and pay attention. If you don't have a compiler warning, add -Wall to the g++ command, and note that `y` is not being used inside the function, and that doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to implement it like this:

```
bool Student::operator < (const Student otherStu)
{
   bool less = false;
   if (year < otherStu.year)
      less = true;
   return less;
}
```

Because now your definition and declaration doesnt match, thay have different return value.

or you can doi just:

```
bool Student::operator < (const Student b)
{
   return year < b.year ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting example where naming something contributes negatively to readability, as opposed to `return year < otherStu.year;`.